# SQL Basic: Group by function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a table that would outline two group by functions but having some minor difficulty.

```
select 
    to_char("CreateTime", 'YYYY-MM') as MonthYear,
    floor(sum("Time"))::integer / 60 as "#MinutesWorkouts",
    sum(case when "Type" = 29 then 1 else 0 end) as "#Streaming",
    (sum(case when "Type" = 29 then "Time" else 0 end))::integer / 60 as "StreamingMinutes",
    sum(case when "Type" = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as "#GuidedProgram",
    sum(case when "Type" = 28 then 1 else 0 end) as "#Tall"
from 
    match_history
WHERE
    "MachineId" = {{Machine_Id}}
GROUP by 
    to_char("CreateTime", 'YYYY-MM')
```

Ideally - I'd like to showcase Machine ID in the column along with the dates. Currently the result shows as (image link) as it only shows the monthyear as the group function. I would like to ensure it shows machine ID on the column too as I'd like to add multiple machine IDs.

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is very product specific.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want both sample table data _and_ the expected result as properly formatted text (i.e. no images, no links.)

Comment: Perhaps all you need is to add `machineid` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Currently using POSTGRE through metabase. Thanks @jarlh for the minimal rep example link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add machine_id ?

```
select 
    to_char("CreateTime", 'YYYY-MM') as MonthYear,
    "MachineId",
    floor(sum("Time"))::integer / 60 as "#MinutesWorkouts",
    sum(case when "Type" = 29 then 1 else 0 end) as "#Streaming",
    (sum(case when "Type" = 29 then "Time" else 0 end))::integer / 60 as "StreamingMinutes",
    sum(case when "Type" = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as "#GuidedProgram",
    sum(case when "Type" = 28 then 1 else 0 end) as "#Tall"
from 
    match_history
GROUP by 
    to_char("CreateTime", 'YYYY-MM'), "MachineId"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. A rookie Q: I should be able to add a where clause in that query correct? Where "MachineID" = 231238912 which should be specific to that query correct? That query shows all the MachineIDs from the table.

Comment: Yes you can add your where clause (WHERE "MachineID" = 231238912) before GROUP BY block